# When define locale text file, language key (eg:'en') or text key (eg:'WELCOME_MESSAGE'), which one should be the outermost key?

Tags: coding-style, localization, map

When define a locale text map, I can use:

1.locale key first

```
{
    "en":{
      "WELCOME_TO_USE_THIS_APP":"Welcome to use this app,...",
      "SOME_OTHER_TEXT":"fsdfsf..."
    },
    "es":{
      "WELCOME_TO_USE_THIS_APP":"Bienvenido a usar esta aplicación, ...",
      "SOME_OTHER_TEXT":"fkdjsklfs..."
    }
}
```

2.text key first:

```
{
    "WELCOME_TO_USE_THIS_APP":{
      "en":"Welcome to use this app,...",
      "es":"Bienvenido a usar esta aplicación, ..."
    },
    "SOME_OTHER_TEXT":{
      "en":"fsdfs...",
      "es":"fkdjsklfs..."
    }
}
```

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In practice, the locale-specific translations for a project will almost certainly not only be organized by language, but also stored in *separate files* per language. As Aganju wrote, this makes things easier for the translators. But it is also easier for the developer; imagine you quickly have to integrate three new languages - would you rather merge in three separate files or three huge changesets to the *same* file?

Answer (score 2):

The latter is a lot easier for the translator.

The former will put all texts from one language next to each other in the memory, which might make access infinitesimaly faster.

Unless this quantum of performance becomes relevant, I'd say the latter is preferable.

Comment: I think you are right because the hardest thing about this is making sure that the app is translated the same the for all languages. Your solution helps nicely with this.